# jqGrid show image in row from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

im trying to display images from records in jqGrid but it's not working.

Every record in my jqGrid has an id. To get the images out of my database table i wrote a ActionResult that returns a File (image) which is stored in the database table to the id.

Because every record has a unique id i'm having a hidden field in my page where jq should store the actual id of the actual record which is formated to the formatter.

When i look through the code with firebug, it seems that the way with the hidden field is not working.

Maybe you have an idea?

Here is my code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cellvalue" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#PartialIndexGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()/IndexGridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Details', 'Bearbeiten','Bild', 'Titel', 'Bearbeitungsort', 'Status'],
        colModel: [
              { name: 'Details', index: "Details", edittype: 'select', align: "center", width: 45, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Shared/Details/', addParam: ''} },
              { name: 'Bearbeiten', index: "Bearbeiten", edittype: 'select', align: "center", width: 80, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Shared/Edit/', addParam: ''} },
              { name: 'Bild', index: 'Bild', edittype: 'image', formatter: imageFormatter },
              { name: 'Titel', index: 'Titel'},
              { name: 'Bearbeitungsort', index: 'Bearbeitungsort' },
              { name: 'AuftragStatus', index: 'AuftragStatus'}
            ],
        pager: $("#PartialIndexGridpager"),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'Titel',
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 942, 
        caption: ''
    })
});
function imageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        $("cellvalue").val(cellvalue);
        return '<img src="@Url.Action("AuftragDBImage", "Shared", new { id = Request.Form["cellvalue"]})" />';
};
```

```
public ActionResult AuftragDBImage(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var auftrag = _db.Auftrag.Where(x => x.Auftrag_GUID == id).Select(x => x).Single();
            return File(auftrag.Bild, "image/jpeg");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return File(pfaddummybild, "image/jpeg");
        }
    }
```

Regards, 
float

Comment: I don't found any hidden field in the jqGrid, but you wrote "it seems that the way with the hidden field is not working". Moreover the custom formatter `imageFormatter` looks like strange. To make possible other people to verify your code you should explain which values for `Build` coulmn has the JSON response from the server and what results should the custom formatter produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered the formatter? I think you need to do this before you load the grid. Here's an example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $.fn.fmatter.imageFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
       return "<img src='/Shared/AuftragDBImage?id=" + cellvalue + "'/>";
  }; 
</script>
```

Note that you don't have a Request.Form object in the formatter (remember you're on the client), so use the regular url.

Comment: You are right with the Request.Form object. That was the problem. Now it gets into my controller action. But it works without formatter registration.

Comment: And of course there is no need for using a hidden field, because the cellvalue is a variable in the formatter.